# I want to try to make 4 lines that are opposite each other, but the length doesn't seem to be the same and the slant angle is also the same

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to try to make 4 lines opposite each other using svg, which I just learned from the course. it should be opposite each other and have the same angle. but in my case all the lines looked different from each other.

I've searched websites for various svg generators, but I don't seem to understand how to use them.
and think of manually x1, y1 and x2, y2 but nope ... the results are asymmetrical (not to mention I'm bad in math).

```css
.chart {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2
}

.pop {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 47%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%)
}

svg {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop">
  <svg class="chart" width="300" height="300">
    <line x1="110" y1="110" x2="70" y2="70"></line>
    <line x1="180" y1="180" x2="220" y2="220"></line>
    <line x1="220" y1="70" x2="175" y2="115"></line>
    <line x1="70" y1="220" x2="115" y2="175"></line>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/BunchOfPaper/pen/gNMEdQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the SVG markup values with what you are trying to achieve:

```
<div class="pop">
  <svg class="chart" width="300" height="300">
    <line x1="75" y1="75" x2="125" y2="125"></line>
    <line x1="225" y1="225" x2="175" y2="175"></line>
    <line x1="225" y1="75" x2="175" y2="125"></line>
    <line x1="75" y1="225" x2="125" y2="175"></line>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The idea is the first `x1` and `y1` is where the starting point of the line is and the `x2` and `y2` is the end point. You don't necessarily have to be good at math :)

Here's the pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dBpWMb

Here's a pen with your pulsar:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqXmKO

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. appreciate it :)

Comment: Cool! In the first pen, I put in two red squares so you can see how you can measure without having to do all the math.